# Identifying a certain quotient with a familiar group

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $a,b\geq 2$ be integers and $N$ the image of the homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}_a\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{ab}, \;\;\;[k]_a\mapsto[kb]_{ab}$$
Identify the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_{ab}/N$ with a familiar group.

I have done quite a bit of thinking about this problem, and it seems that the best strategy would be to try and find an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{ab}/N$ to another group such that the kernel is $N$. The other group should be a familiar group. If this is the correct approach, I'm not sure how to proceed. If it isn't, I would greatly appreciate any hints/guidance.

Comment: I think $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{ab}}{N} \cong \mathbb{Z}_b$. Maybe try to construct a concrete isomorphism from here.

Comment: Wouldn't a counter example for that be the case when $a, b = 2$? In that case, $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{ab}}{N}$ would have three elements while $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ has two.

Comment: @algebraicgeometer22 taking $a = b = 2$, then $N = \{[0]_{ab},[2]_{ab}\}$ and so, $|\Bbb{Z}_{ab}/N| = \frac{4}{2} = 2 = |\Bbb{Z}_2|$.

Comment: Let $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, \overline{3}\}$. Then $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_4}{\langle \overline{0}, \overline{2} \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ right? 

Moreover, $\mathbb{Z}_{4}/N$ can not have $3$ elements at all because $3$ does not divide $4$.

Comment: You are both correct. Somehow, I forgot how to quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi$ be the homomorphism. We have that
$$\Bbb{Z}_a/\ker \varphi \simeq N.$$
Take some $k \in \Bbb{Z}_a$, then $[k]_a \in \ker\varphi$ iff $[kb]_{ab} = [0]_{ab}$.

Now, finding $\ker\varphi$ is easy to get $N$ and so $\Bbb{Z}_{ab}/N$.

Comment: At first glance, it seems that $\ker \varphi$ is trivial. If that's the case, are you suggesting that $\mathbb{Z}_{ab}/N$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{ab}}{\mathbb{Z}_a}$?

Comment: @algebraicgeometer22 exactly.

Comment: I see. This is why $\mathbb{Z}_{ab}/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_b$. Thank you!

Comment: @algebraicgeometer22 you can construct an explicit isomorphism. Since they have the same order and are cyclic, maps the generator in another generator.